# @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function-Jetpack

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-webview

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Composable
fun WebPageScreen(urlToRender: String) {
    AndroidView(factory = {
        WebView(it).apply {
            layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
            webViewClient = WebViewClient()
            loadUrl(urlToRender)
        }
    }, update = {
        it.loadUrl(urlToRender)
    })
}


@Composable
fun MainContent() {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color(0xFFFEFEFA))
            .padding(16.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(32.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {

        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.link), contentDescription = "Localized description", contentScale = ContentScale.Crop, modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(150.dp)
                .clickable(enabled = true, onClickLabel = "Clickable image",
                    onClick = {
                        
                        WebPageScreen("https://www.google.co.in/")

                    }
                )
        )

    }
}
```

This is my code ,I want to implement webview when i click the image,I'm getting error like "@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function". Anyone Please help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your'e having this error because `onClick` is not a composable while you are calling a function annotated with `@Composable` inside of it (`WebPageScreen)`

> @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a
> @Composable function

Either you remove the `@Composable` annotation in the `WebPageScreen` though I'm not sure if something will break (never tried webviews in compose yet).

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Composable // <- remove this line
fun WebPageScreen(urlToRender: String) { ... }
```

Or you can try having a `url` `mutableState` like this, where its initial state is an empty string, and upon clicking the image its value will change forcing the `MainContent` to `re-compose` and calling the `WebPageScreen(<url>)`

```
@Composable
fun MainContent() {
    
    ...
    
    var url by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    // at first composition pass this will be ignored
    if (url.isNotBlank()) {
        WebPageScreen(url)
    }

    Column(
       ...
    ) {

        Image(
            ...
            ...
            .clickable(enabled = true, onClickLabel = "Clickable image",
                    onClick = {
                        // setting a value to this will trigger re-composition of MainContent, satisfying your if condition above
                        url = "https://www.google.co.in/"
                    }
                )
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried mutablestate method,it's not working,can u give anyother solution for this?

Comment: I'm not sure what's not working, I just tried my answer, it compiles fine and upon clicking the button the `MainContent` re-composes and satisfying the if block, my answer solves your problem with `@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function`, if your `WebView` doesn't load, its a different issue now I guess